# Azure Compute Emulator does not start. DFAgent crashes with error

Tags: azure

Run in to problem when start default mvc project from visual studio. I tryed to change _CSRUN_STATE_DIRECTORY and reinstaled azure sdk. But still no effect.

DFFabricLog:

```
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.252, 1, 1, Information, 201523206, Loading Providers`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.267, 2, 1, Information, 201523231, Done reading configuration from {0}`C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\Emulator\devfabric\DevFC.exe.Config`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.271, 3, 1, Information, 201523243, Loading Configuration.`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.352, 4, 1, Information, 201523233, {0} file not found in CWD. Extracting from dll resources.`Fabric.StockBindings.xml`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.356, 5, 1, Information, 201523242, Loading binding configuration.`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.373, 6, 1, Information, 201523242, Total {0} binding configurations loaded.`19`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.373, 7, 1, Information, 201523242, Loading binding configuration.`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.378, 8, 1, Information, 201523242, Total {0} binding configurations loaded.`19`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.379, 9, 1, Information, 201523234, {0} file not found in CWD. Extracting from dll resources.`Fabric.StockBehaviors.xml`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.381, 10, 1, Information, 201523241, Loading service behavior configuration.`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.386, 11, 1, Information, 201523241, Total {0} service behavior configurations loaded.`2`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.386, 12, 1, Information, 201523241, Loading endpoint behavior configuration.`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.386, 13, 1, Information, 201523241, Total {0} endpoint behavior configurations loaded.`0`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.386, 14, 1, Information, 201523241, Loading service behavior configuration.`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.386, 15, 1, Information, 201523241, Total {0} service behavior configurations loaded.`2`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.386, 16, 1, Information, 201523241, Loading endpoint behavior configuration.`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.386, 17, 1, Information, 201523241, Total {0} endpoint behavior configurations loaded.`0`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.386, 18, 1, Information, 201523243, Done Loading Configuration.`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.386, 19, 1, Information, 201523232, AppConfig Config Source deleting its artifacts.`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.386, 20, 1, Information, 201523232, Deleting AppConfig Config Source artifact {0}`C:\Users\KochekovskySA\AppData\Local\Temp\Fabric.StockBindings.xmlea27fd29-6349-47dc-93ba-bd14d830a8fd`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.386, 21, 1, Information, 201523232, Deleting AppConfig Config Source artifact {0}`C:\Users\KochekovskySA\AppData\Local\Temp\Fabric.StockBehaviors.xml9dc12dcd-2f6d-43ca-9769-3a496e71cc90`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.390, 22, 1, Information, 201523206, CommunicationFramework initialized with configuration source type: {0}`AppConfig`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.436, 23, 4, Information, 201523202, CreateService called for {0}`Microsoft.ServiceHosting.Tools.DevelopmentFabric.NetworkInformation.PxeDHCPResponder`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.441, 24, 4, Information, 201523202, Logging event CommFxServiceHostCreated with params: ServiceName={0} `Microsoft.ServiceHosting.Tools.DevelopmentFabric.NetworkInformation.PxeDHCPResponder`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.456, 25, 4, Information, 201523251, GetServiceBehaviors called for behavior config {0}`FabricServiceBehavior`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.456, 26, 4, Verbose, 201523249, GetServiceBehaviorConfiguration called for configuration {0}`FabricServiceBehavior`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.457, 27, 4, Information, 201523254, Creating service behavior {0}`System.ServiceModel.Description.IServiceBehavior`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.457, 28, 4, Information, 201523254, Copying properties for service behavior {0}`System.ServiceModel.Description.IServiceBehavior`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.457, 29, 4, Information, 201523254, Creating service behavior {0}`System.ServiceModel.Description.IServiceBehavior`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.457, 30, 4, Information, 201523254, Copying properties for service behavior {0}`System.ServiceModel.Description.IServiceBehavior`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.458, 31, 4, Information, 201523253, Ignoring the DataContractSerializerServiceBehavior.`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.458, 32, 4, Information, 201523254, Creating service behavior {0}`System.ServiceModel.Description.IServiceBehavior`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.458, 33, 4, Information, 201523254, Copying properties for service behavior {0}`System.ServiceModel.Description.IServiceBehavior`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.459, 34, 4, Information, 201523254, Creating service behavior {0}`System.ServiceModel.Description.IServiceBehavior`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.459, 35, 4, Information, 201523254, Copying properties for service behavior {0}`System.ServiceModel.Description.IServiceBehavior`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.459, 36, 4, Information, 201523251, Returning {0} service behaviors for the behavior config {1}`4`FabricServiceBehavior`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.460, 37, 4, Verbose, 201523256, GetBindingFromConfig called.`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.461, 38, 4, Verbose, 201523250, GetBindingConfiguration called for configuration {0}`PxeNetTcpBinding`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.461, 39, 4, Information, 201523257, Created binding of type {0}`System.ServiceModel.NetTcpBinding`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.461, 40, 4, Information, 201523257, Applying configuration {0} to binding type {1}`PxeNetTcpBinding`System.ServiceModel.NetTcpBinding`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.463, 41, 4, Information, 201523203, StartService called for {0}`Microsoft.ServiceHosting.Tools.DevelopmentFabric.NetworkInformation.PxeDHCPResponder`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.464, 42, 4, Verbose, 201523225, ServiceHost.Open called for service {0}.`PxeDHCPResponder`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.464, 43, 4, Information, 201523225, Logging event CommFxServiceHostOpened with params: ServiceName={0} `PxeDHCPResponder`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.519, 44, 1, Information, 49153, Node 27c0ade8-285e-4250-b10d-cabc5daccfef BeginWorkflow, : Reset workflow from {0}`BeginWorkflow`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.525, 45, 1, Warning, 49171, Node 27c0ade8-285e-4250-b10d-cabc5daccfef: Set agent version to unknown. Skip building dependency graph.`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.525, 46, 1, Information, 0, LogicalNode`Initializing Logical Node`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.532, 47, 1, Information, 201523208, CreateClient called for contract {0} with bindingConfigName {1} and IP endpoint {2}`RD.Fabric.Controller.IAgent`LargeNetTcpBinding`net.tcp://localhost:15098/dfagent/1/host`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.532, 48, 1, Verbose, 201523256, GetBindingFromConfig called.`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.532, 49, 1, Verbose, 201523250, GetBindingConfiguration called for configuration {0}`LargeNetTcpBinding`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.533, 50, 1, Information, 201523257, Created binding of type {0}`System.ServiceModel.NetTcpBinding`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.533, 51, 1, Information, 201523257, Applying configuration {0} to binding type {1}`LargeNetTcpBinding`System.ServiceModel.NetTcpBinding`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.541, 52, 1, Information, 201523208, Logging event CommFxClientCreated with params: ContractName={0} `RD.Fabric.Controller.IAgent`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.541, 53, 1, Information, 201523208, CreateClient called for contract {0} with bindingConfigName {1} and IP endpoint {2}`RD.Fabric.Controller.IDevelopmentAgent`LargeNetTcpBinding`net.tcp://localhost:15098/dfagent/1/host`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.542, 54, 1, Verbose, 201523256, GetBindingFromConfig called.`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.542, 55, 1, Verbose, 201523250, GetBindingConfiguration called for configuration {0}`LargeNetTcpBinding`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.542, 56, 1, Information, 201523257, Created binding of type {0}`System.ServiceModel.NetTcpBinding`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.543, 57, 1, Information, 201523257, Applying configuration {0} to binding type {1}`LargeNetTcpBinding`System.ServiceModel.NetTcpBinding`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.544, 58, 1, Information, 201523208, Logging event CommFxClientCreated with params: ContractName={0} `RD.Fabric.Controller.IDevelopmentAgent`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.544, 59, 1, Information, 201523202, CreateService called for {0}`RD.Fabric.Controller.DevFabricAgentInterface`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.545, 60, 1, Information, 201523202, Logging event CommFxServiceHostCreated with params: ServiceName={0} `RD.Fabric.Controller.DevFabricAgentInterface`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.545, 61, 1, Verbose, 201523256, GetBindingFromConfig called.`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.545, 62, 1, Verbose, 201523250, GetBindingConfiguration called for configuration {0}`LargeNetTcpBinding`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.546, 63, 1, Information, 201523257, Created binding of type {0}`System.ServiceModel.NetTcpBinding`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.546, 64, 1, Information, 201523257, Applying configuration {0} to binding type {1}`LargeNetTcpBinding`System.ServiceModel.NetTcpBinding`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.546, 65, 1, Information, 201523203, StartService called for {0}`RD.Fabric.Controller.DevFabricAgentInterface`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.546, 66, 1, Verbose, 201523225, ServiceHost.Open called for service {0}.`DevFabricAgentInterface`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.547, 67, 1, Information, 201523225, Logging event CommFxServiceHostOpened with params: ServiceName={0} `DevFabricAgentInterface`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.547, 68, 1, Information, 201523251, GetServiceBehaviors called for behavior config {0}`FabricServiceBehavior`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.547, 69, 1, Verbose, 201523249, GetServiceBehaviorConfiguration called for configuration {0}`FabricServiceBehavior`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.547, 70, 1, Information, 201523254, Creating service behavior {0}`System.ServiceModel.Description.IServiceBehavior`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.548, 71, 1, Information, 201523254, Copying properties for service behavior {0}`System.ServiceModel.Description.IServiceBehavior`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.548, 72, 1, Information, 201523254, Creating service behavior {0}`System.ServiceModel.Description.IServiceBehavior`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.548, 73, 1, Information, 201523254, Copying properties for service behavior {0}`System.ServiceModel.Description.IServiceBehavior`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.549, 74, 1, Information, 201523253, Ignoring the DataContractSerializerServiceBehavior.`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.549, 75, 1, Information, 201523254, Creating service behavior {0}`System.ServiceModel.Description.IServiceBehavior`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.549, 76, 1, Information, 201523254, Copying properties for service behavior {0}`System.ServiceModel.Description.IServiceBehavior`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.549, 77, 1, Information, 201523254, Creating service behavior {0}`System.ServiceModel.Description.IServiceBehavior`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.550, 78, 1, Information, 201523254, Copying properties for service behavior {0}`System.ServiceModel.Description.IServiceBehavior`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.550, 79, 1, Information, 201523251, Returning {0} service behaviors for the behavior config {1}`4`FabricServiceBehavior`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.559, 80, 1, Information, 0, LogicalNode`Agent Interface Initialized`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.560, 81, 14, Information, 0, Calling to Poll Health from PollAgent code`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.561, 82, 1, Information, 0, Starting DevFabric...`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.561, 83, 1, Information, 0, Starting Repository Service...`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.561, 84, 1, Information, 201523202, CreateService called for {0}`Microsoft.Windows.Azure.DevFabric.RepositoryService`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.571, 85, 14, Information, 49153, new version {0} of goal data is picked up.`0`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.572, 86, 1, Information, 201523202, Logging event CommFxServiceHostCreated with params: ServiceName={0} `Microsoft.Windows.Azure.DevFabric.RepositoryService`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.572, 87, 1, Verbose, 201523256, GetBindingFromConfig called.`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.573, 88, 1, Verbose, 201523250, GetBindingConfiguration called for configuration {0}`LargeNetTcpBinding`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.573, 89, 1, Information, 201523257, Created binding of type {0}`System.ServiceModel.NetTcpBinding`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.573, 90, 1, Information, 201523257, Applying configuration {0} to binding type {1}`LargeNetTcpBinding`System.ServiceModel.NetTcpBinding`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.574, 91, 1, Information, 201523203, StartService called for {0}`Microsoft.Windows.Azure.DevFabric.RepositoryService`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.574, 92, 1, Verbose, 201523225, ServiceHost.Open called for service {0}.`RepositoryService`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.574, 93, 1, Information, 201523225, Logging event CommFxServiceHostOpened with params: ServiceName={0} `RepositoryService`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.574, 94, 14, Information, 49153, Node 27c0ade8-285e-4250-b10d-cabc5daccfef BeginWorkflow, : Reset workflow from {0}`BeginWorkflow`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.575, 95, 1, Information, 201523251, GetServiceBehaviors called for behavior config {0}`FabricServiceBehavior`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.575, 96, 1, Verbose, 201523249, GetServiceBehaviorConfiguration called for configuration {0}`FabricServiceBehavior`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.575, 97, 1, Information, 201523254, Creating service behavior {0}`System.ServiceModel.Description.IServiceBehavior`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.576, 98, 1, Information, 201523254, Copying properties for service behavior {0}`System.ServiceModel.Description.IServiceBehavior`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.576, 99, 1, Information, 201523254, Creating service behavior {0}`System.ServiceModel.Description.IServiceBehavior`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.576, 100, 1, Information, 201523254, Copying properties for service behavior {0}`System.ServiceModel.Description.IServiceBehavior`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.576, 101, 1, Information, 201523253, Ignoring the DataContractSerializerServiceBehavior.`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.576, 102, 1, Information, 201523254, Creating service behavior {0}`System.ServiceModel.Description.IServiceBehavior`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.576, 103, 1, Information, 201523254, Copying properties for service behavior {0}`System.ServiceModel.Description.IServiceBehavior`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.576, 104, 1, Information, 201523254, Creating service behavior {0}`System.ServiceModel.Description.IServiceBehavior`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.576, 105, 1, Information, 201523254, Copying properties for service behavior {0}`System.ServiceModel.Description.IServiceBehavior`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.576, 106, 1, Information, 201523251, Returning {0} service behaviors for the behavior config {1}`4`FabricServiceBehavior`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.578, 107, 14, Information, 201523223, Contract: RD.Fabric.Controller.IAgent Checking channel terminal states.`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.578, 108, 14, Information, 201523222, Contract: RD.Fabric.Controller.IAgent Creating channel.`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.594, 109, 1, Information, 0, Repository Service is up and running...`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.595, 110, 1, Information, 0, Starting Management Service...`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.595, 111, 1, Information, 201523202, CreateService called for {0}`Microsoft.Windows.Azure.DevFabric.DevFabricManagement`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.600, 112, 1, Information, 201523202, Logging event CommFxServiceHostCreated with params: ServiceName={0} `Microsoft.Windows.Azure.DevFabric.DevFabricManagement`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.600, 113, 1, Verbose, 201523256, GetBindingFromConfig called.`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.600, 114, 1, Verbose, 201523250, GetBindingConfiguration called for configuration {0}`LargeNetTcpBinding`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.600, 115, 1, Information, 201523257, Created binding of type {0}`System.ServiceModel.NetTcpBinding`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.600, 116, 1, Information, 201523257, Applying configuration {0} to binding type {1}`LargeNetTcpBinding`System.ServiceModel.NetTcpBinding`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.600, 117, 1, Verbose, 201523256, GetBindingFromConfig called.`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.600, 118, 1, Verbose, 201523250, GetBindingConfiguration called for configuration {0}`LargeNetTcpBinding`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.600, 119, 1, Information, 201523257, Created binding of type {0}`System.ServiceModel.NetTcpBinding`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.601, 120, 1, Information, 201523257, Applying configuration {0} to binding type {1}`LargeNetTcpBinding`System.ServiceModel.NetTcpBinding`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.601, 121, 1, Information, 201523203, StartService called for {0}`Microsoft.Windows.Azure.DevFabric.DevFabricManagement`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.601, 122, 1, Verbose, 201523225, ServiceHost.Open called for service {0}.`DevFabricManagement`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.601, 123, 1, Information, 201523225, Logging event CommFxServiceHostOpened with params: ServiceName={0} `DevFabricManagement`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.601, 124, 1, Information, 201523251, GetServiceBehaviors called for behavior config {0}`FabricServiceBehavior`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.601, 125, 1, Verbose, 201523249, GetServiceBehaviorConfiguration called for configuration {0}`FabricServiceBehavior`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.601, 126, 1, Information, 201523254, Creating service behavior {0}`System.ServiceModel.Description.IServiceBehavior`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.601, 127, 1, Information, 201523254, Copying properties for service behavior {0}`System.ServiceModel.Description.IServiceBehavior`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.601, 128, 1, Information, 201523254, Creating service behavior {0}`System.ServiceModel.Description.IServiceBehavior`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.601, 129, 1, Information, 201523254, Copying properties for service behavior {0}`System.ServiceModel.Description.IServiceBehavior`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.601, 130, 1, Information, 201523253, Ignoring the DataContractSerializerServiceBehavior.`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.601, 131, 1, Information, 201523254, Creating service behavior {0}`System.ServiceModel.Description.IServiceBehavior`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.601, 132, 1, Information, 201523254, Copying properties for service behavior {0}`System.ServiceModel.Description.IServiceBehavior`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.601, 133, 1, Information, 201523254, Creating service behavior {0}`System.ServiceModel.Description.IServiceBehavior`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.601, 134, 1, Information, 201523254, Copying properties for service behavior {0}`System.ServiceModel.Description.IServiceBehavior`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.601, 135, 1, Information, 201523251, Returning {0} service behaviors for the behavior config {1}`4`FabricServiceBehavior`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.608, 136, 14, Information, 201523224, Contract: RD.Fabric.Controller.IAgent Configuring channel factory with default and custom behaviors.`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.613, 137, 1, Information, 0, Management Service is up and running...`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.615, 138, 1, Information, 0, DevFabric is up and running...`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.618, 139, 14, Information, 201523223, Contract: RD.Fabric.Controller.IAgent Channel state is {0}`Created`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.618, 140, 14, Information, 201523220, Contract: RD.Fabric.Controller.IAgent GetChannel did not require channel recycle. Reusing existing channel.`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.619, 141, 14, Verbose, 0, 898878e0-3e5d-4335-8a1a-ada2578c2aa8`GetAgentState`System.Object[]`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:53.621, 142, 14, Information, 201523260, Logging event CommFxClientOperationInvoked with params: Id={0} TimeAtActionInvoke={1} ClientVersion={2} ClientCapabilities={3} From={4} To={5} Action={6} `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`10.07.2012 4:57:53`<null>`<null>`KOCHEKOVSKY`net.tcp://localhost:15098/dfagent/1/host`IAgent/GetState`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:55.702, 143, 14, Error, 0, 898878e0-3e5d-4335-8a1a-ada2578c2aa8`GetAgentState`System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: ?? ??????? ???????????? ? net.tcp://localhost:15098/dfagent/1/host. ??????? ??????????? ??????????? ? ??????? ????????? ??????? 00:00:02.0014000. ??? ?????? TCP 10061: ??????????? ?? ???????????, ?.?. ???????? ????????? ?????? ?????? ?? ??????????? 127.0.0.1:15098.  ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: ??????????? ?? ???????????, ?.?. ???????? ????????? ?????? ?????? ?? ??????????? 127.0.0.1:15098
   ? System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   ? System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect(EndPoint remoteEP)
   ? System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnectionInitiator.Connect(Uri uri, TimeSpan timeout)
   --- ????? ??????????? ??????????? ????? ?????????? ---

Server stack trace: 
   ? System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnectionInitiator.Connect(Uri uri, TimeSpan timeout)
   ? System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedConnectionInitiator.Connect(Uri uri, TimeSpan timeout)
   ? System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionPoolHelper.EstablishConnection(TimeSpan timeout)
   ? System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   ? System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   ? System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   ? System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   ? System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOpenOnce.System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ICallOnce.Call(ServiceChannel channel, TimeSpan timeout)
   ? System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOnceManager.CallOnce(TimeSpan timeout, CallOnceManager cascade)
   ? System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   ? System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   ? System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   ? System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   ? System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   ? RD.Fabric.Controller.IAgent.GetState()
   ? RD.Fabric.Controller.DevFabricAgentInterface.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<GetAgentState>b__2a(IAgent agent)
   ? RD.Fabric.Controller.DevFabricAgentInterface.CallAgent(AgentCallDelegate agentCall, String operation)`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:55.702, 144, 14, Information, 0, GetAgentState fails.`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:56.703, 145, 14, Information, 0, Calling to Poll Health from PollAgent code`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:56.703, 146, 14, Information, 201523223, Contract: RD.Fabric.Controller.IAgent Checking channel terminal states.`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:56.703, 147, 14, Information, 201523223, Contract: RD.Fabric.Controller.IAgent Channel state is {0}`Faulted`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:56.703, 148, 14, Information, 201523219, Contract: RD.Fabric.Controller.IAgent GetChannel required channel recycle. Returning new channel.`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:56.704, 149, 14, Information, 201523222, Contract: RD.Fabric.Controller.IAgent Creating channel.`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:56.704, 150, 14, Information, 201523224, Contract: RD.Fabric.Controller.IAgent Configuring channel factory with default and custom behaviors.`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:56.704, 151, 14, Verbose, 0, 898878e0-3e5d-4335-8a1a-ada2578c2aa8`GetAgentState`System.Object[]`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:56.704, 152, 14, Information, 201523260, Logging event CommFxClientOperationInvoked with params: Id={0} TimeAtActionInvoke={1} ClientVersion={2} ClientCapabilities={3} From={4} To={5} Action={6} `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`10.07.2012 4:57:56`<null>`<null>`KOCHEKOVSKY`net.tcp://localhost:15098/dfagent/1/host`IAgent/GetState`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:58.715, 153, 14, Error, 0, 898878e0-3e5d-4335-8a1a-ada2578c2aa8`GetAgentState`System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: ?? ??????? ???????????? ? net.tcp://localhost:15098/dfagent/1/host. ??????? ??????????? ??????????? ? ??????? ????????? ??????? 00:00:02.0094056. ??? ?????? TCP 10061: ??????????? ?? ???????????, ?.?. ???????? ????????? ?????? ?????? ?? ??????????? 127.0.0.1:15098.  ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: ??????????? ?? ???????????, ?.?. ???????? ????????? ?????? ?????? ?? ??????????? 127.0.0.1:15098
   ? System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   ? System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect(EndPoint remoteEP)
   ? System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnectionInitiator.Connect(Uri uri, TimeSpan timeout)
   --- ????? ??????????? ??????????? ????? ?????????? ---

Server stack trace: 
   ? System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnectionInitiator.Connect(Uri uri, TimeSpan timeout)
   ? System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedConnectionInitiator.Connect(Uri uri, TimeSpan timeout)
   ? System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionPoolHelper.EstablishConnection(TimeSpan timeout)
   ? System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   ? System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   ? System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   ? System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   ? System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOpenOnce.System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ICallOnce.Call(ServiceChannel channel, TimeSpan timeout)
   ? System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOnceManager.CallOnce(TimeSpan timeout, CallOnceManager cascade)
   ? System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   ? System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   ? System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   ? System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   ? System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   ? RD.Fabric.Controller.IAgent.GetState()
   ? RD.Fabric.Controller.DevFabricAgentInterface.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<GetAgentState>b__2a(IAgent agent)
   ? RD.Fabric.Controller.DevFabricAgentInterface.CallAgent(AgentCallDelegate agentCall, String operation)`
---
2012-7-10T4:57:58.716, 154, 14, Information, 0, GetAgentState fails.`
```

DFAgentLog:

```
[2012/07/06, 08:48:31.363,  INFO, 00009220] StorageRoot: C:\DFTemp
[2012/07/06, 08:48:31.544,  INFO, 00009220] The parameters and the method signature does not match
[2012/07/06, 08:48:31.547,  INFO, 00009220]    в System.Reflection.RuntimeParameterInfo.GetParameters(IRuntimeMethodInfo methodHandle, MemberInfo member, Signature sig, ParameterInfo& returnParameter, Boolean fetchReturnParameter)
   в System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.FetchNonReturnParameters()
   в System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.GetParameters()
   в System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceReflector.ValidateParameterMetadata(MethodInfo methodInfo)
   в System.ServiceModel.Description.TypeLoader.CreateOperationDescriptions(ContractDescription contractDescription, ContractReflectionInfo reflectionInfo, Type contractToGetMethodsFrom, ContractDescription declaringContract, MessageDirection direction)
   в System.ServiceModel.Description.TypeLoader.CreateContractDescription(ServiceContractAttribute contractAttr, Type contractType, Type serviceType, ContractReflectionInfo& reflectionInfo, Object serviceImplementation)
   в System.ServiceModel.Description.TypeLoader.LoadContractDescriptionHelper(Type contractType, Type serviceType, Object serviceImplementation)
   в System.ServiceModel.Description.TypeLoader.CreateContractDescription(ServiceContractAttribute contractAttr, Type contractType, Type serviceType, ContractReflectionInfo& reflectionInfo, Object serviceImplementation)
   в System.ServiceModel.Description.TypeLoader.LoadContractDescriptionHelper(Type contractType, Type serviceType, Object serviceImplementation)
   в System.ServiceModel.Description.ContractDescription.GetContract(Type contractType, Object serviceImplementation)
   в System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost.CreateDescription(IDictionary`2& implementedContracts)
   в System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.InitializeDescription(UriSchemeKeyedCollection baseAddresses)
   в System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost.InitializeDescription(Type serviceType, UriSchemeKeyedCollection baseAddresses)
   в System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost..ctor(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
   в Microsoft.Windows.Azure.Fabric.Cfx.Contracts.CommunicationFrameworkServ
```

Comment: Based on this log file it seems that there is a mismatch somewhere on which method is being called via reflection when the agent is starting up.  Did this machine have previous versions of the SDK installed as well?  When you use the csrun command as Avkash indicated can you verify that the correct emulator is starting up?  Maybe use process explorer and look at the process to verify the correct csrun (correct for the version of SDK you have in your application) is being used?  Maybe there are multiple SDKs in your path?

Comment: One sdk, one emulator and one csrun on my dev computer.

Answer (score 3):

I may not have the exact reason what is happening in your machine but can help you to troubleshoot this issue by trying as following steps:

1. Be sure that Azure DevFabric is not running in your machine
2. Now open Windows Azure SDK 1.7 command prompt in Admin mode and set as below (Be sure to have "newdftemp" folder as described below):

   > set _CSRUN_STATE_DIRECTORY=C:\newdftemp
3. Launch dev Fabric as below:

   > csrun /devfabric:start
4. This will launch Azure Emulator and expected to crash based on above problem
5. Now open C:\newdftemp\DevFCLogs folder and you will find a log file DevFabric--*.log. Check this file and see what could be the issue. (The log file will be huge so you can not put all here but it will explain what is not going write and help you)
6. You can also open free Incident to get help from Windows Azure Support team and share this log to get further help as if needed.

Answer (score 3):

After looking the log, here is my investigation:

Agent Configuration is defined as below:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\Emulator\devfabric\DevFC.exe.Config
```

The Agent Port is set to 15098 as below:

```
<DevFCSettings>
    <add key="AgentPort" value="15098" />
</DevFCSettings>
```

Now when agent starts in your machine

```
2012-7-10T4:57:55.702, 143, 14, Error, 0, 898878e0-3e5d-4335-8a1a-ada2578c2aa8`
GetAgentState`System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException:
         net.tcp://localhost:15098/dfagent/1/host.
         127.0.0.1:15098.  ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException:
         127.0.0.1:15098 
? System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
? System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect(EndPoint remoteEP)
? System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnectionInitiator.Connect(Uri uri, TimeSpan timeout)
```

So the main problem is that you are hitting classing WCF "EndpointNotFoundException" exception in your development machine which cause Compute Emulator to crash. You would need to troubleshoot this problem to solve your compute emulator problem.

In one of my previous [similar investigation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2011/11/08/windows-azure-application-error-tcp-error-code-10061-no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-refused-it-127-0-0-1-808.aspx) I found the specific port was consumed by other service so service could not use it. In your case the problem is that endpoint not found.

Here are few suggestions:

[[1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2011/11/08/windows-azure-application-error-tcp-error-code-10061-no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-refused-it-127-0-0-1-808.aspx)] Try repairing Service Model installation on your machine as below:

```
 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319>ServiceModelReg.exe -r
```

[[2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx)] Try enabling the WCF tracing in your DevFC.exe.config as described in this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx). This will help to troubleshoot why your are hitting such exception and provide further step to find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had similar issue with the Visual studio Azure Compute Emulator and was unable to launch any of the cloud projects. 
Here is the work around:

*Problem:*

Azure Emulator Crash with error 0x800700b7: Cannot create a file when that file already exists

*Reason:*

The actual reason behind this issue is missing or failing WMI class.

*Solution:*

1. Go to start-run and type in wmimgmt.msc
2. Right click on Local WMI Control (Local) and select properties.
3. On the general tab, if there are any failures noted on that box, that indicates a core WMI issue.
4. Found the .MOF files for Win32_Processor namespace/class
   [WMI Control Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwzgR.jpg)
5. Repair the MOF file by running mofcomp.exe    'MOFFilename.MOF'. The mofcomp.exe is located in the C:\Windows\System32\wbem folder.
6. And then re-register the associated DLL by running the command regsvr32               'MOFFilename.dll'
   [cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhhPE.jpg)
7. Verify if it is fixed or not by checking the WMI Control (wmimgmt.msc) again. This time, as you can see in the image below, there are no more WMI class erros.
8. Then, re-launch the Emulator, and this time you will see the emulator to run again, with no issues/crash this time.