# Azure Compute Emulator does not start. DFAgent crashes with error (continious)

Tags: c#, azure

Run in to problem when start default mvc project from visual studio. This question is continuation of: [Azure Compute Emulator does not start. DFAgent crashes with error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11391352/azure-compute-emulator-does-not-start-dfagent-crashes-with-error). Also I found this AppCrash log file, that contains information about loaded assemblies but it does not fit to previous question:

```
Version=1
EventType=APPCRASH
EventTime=129860523658697840
ReportType=2
Consent=1
UploadTime=129860523659217892
ReportIdentifier=8caf429b-c768-11e1-a4ed-6cf04951e202
Response.BucketId=3054088369
Response.BucketTable=1
Response.type=4
Sig[0].Name=Application Name
Sig[0].Value=csrun.exe
Sig[1].Name=Application Version
Sig[1].Value=6.0.6002.18488
Sig[2].Name=Application Timestamp
Sig[2].Value=4fcaabdc
Sig[3].Name=Fault Module Name
Sig[3].Value=KERNELBASE.dll
Sig[4].Name=Fault Module Version
Sig[4].Value=6.1.7600.16850
Sig[5].Name=Fault Module Timestamp
Sig[5].Value=4e21132b
Sig[6].Name=Exception Code
Sig[6].Value=e0434f4d
Sig[7].Name=Exception Offset
Sig[7].Value=00009673
DynamicSig[1].Name=Версия ОС
DynamicSig[1].Value=6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.48
DynamicSig[2].Name=Код языка
DynamicSig[2].Value=1049
UI[2]=C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\Emulator\csrun.exe
UI[3]=Прекращена работа программы "Windows Azure Simulation Execution Tool"
UI[4]=Windows может провести поиск способа устранения этой ошибки в Интернете.
UI[5]=Искать решение проблемы в Интернете и закрыть программу
UI[6]=Проверить наличие способа исправления ошибки в Интернете позднее и закрыть программу
UI[7]=Закрыть программу
LoadedModule[0]=C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\Emulator\csrun.exe
LoadedModule[1]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
LoadedModule[2]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MSCOREE.DLL
LoadedModule[3]=C:\Windows\system32\KERNEL32.dll
LoadedModule[4]=C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
LoadedModule[5]=C:\Windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
LoadedModule[6]=C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
LoadedModule[7]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll
LoadedModule[8]=C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
LoadedModule[9]=C:\Windows\system32\apphelp.dll
LoadedModule[10]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorwks.dll
LoadedModule[11]=C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.4927_none_d08a205e442db5b5\MSVCR80.dll
LoadedModule[12]=C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll
LoadedModule[13]=C:\Windows\system32\GDI32.dll
LoadedModule[14]=C:\Windows\system32\LPK.dll
LoadedModule[15]=C:\Windows\system32\USP10.dll
LoadedModule[16]=C:\Windows\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
LoadedModule[17]=C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
LoadedModule[18]=C:\Windows\system32\MSCTF.dll
LoadedModule[19]=C:\PROGRA~1\KASPER~1\KASPER~1.0FO\adialhk.dll
LoadedModule[20]=C:\PROGRA~1\KASPER~1\KASPER~1.0FO\kloehk.dll
LoadedModule[21]=C:\Windows\system32\shell32.dll
LoadedModule[22]=C:\Windows\system32\ole32.dll
LoadedModule[23]=C:\Windows\system32\profapi.dll
LoadedModule[24]=C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll
LoadedModule[25]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorsec.dll
LoadedModule[26]=C:\Windows\system32\WINTRUST.dll
LoadedModule[27]=C:\Windows\system32\CRYPT32.dll
LoadedModule[28]=C:\Windows\system32\MSASN1.dll
LoadedModule[29]=C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.7600.16661_none_ebfb56996c72aefc\COMCTL32.dll
LoadedModule[30]=C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTSP.dll
LoadedModule[31]=C:\Windows\system32\rsaenh.dll
LoadedModule[32]=C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTBASE.dll
LoadedModule[33]=C:\Windows\system32\imagehlp.dll
LoadedModule[34]=C:\Windows\system32\ncrypt.dll
LoadedModule[35]=C:\Windows\system32\bcrypt.dll
LoadedModule[36]=C:\Windows\system32\bcryptprimitives.dll
LoadedModule[37]=C:\Windows\system32\USERENV.dll
LoadedModule[38]=C:\Windows\system32\GPAPI.dll
LoadedModule[39]=C:\Windows\system32\cryptnet.dll
LoadedModule[40]=C:\Windows\system32\WLDAP32.dll
LoadedModule[41]=C:\Windows\system32\SensApi.dll
LoadedModule[42]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorjit.dll
LoadedModule[43]=C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\mscorlib.resources\2.0.0.0_ru_b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.resources.dll
LoadedModule[44]=C:\Windows\system32\VERSION.dll
State[0].Key=Transport.DoneStage1
State[0].Value=1
State[1].Key=DataRequest
State[1].Value=Bucket=-1240878927/nBucketTable=1/nResponse=1/n
FriendlyEventName=APPCRASH
ConsentKey=APPCRASH
AppName=Windows Azure Simulation Execution Tool
AppPath=C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\Emulator\csrun.exe
ReportDescription=Stopped working
```

Comment: Does this happen to every project? If so, please try to reinstall the SDK to see whether it works.

Comment: I already reinstaled sdk several times as described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11391352/azure-compute-emulator-does-not-start-dfagent-crashes-with-error. Have you any recomendations how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Such problems are mainly caused by one misconfiguration in your machine and it would be very hard to troubleshoot however based on your above info I can see 3 possible reason (there may be more..)

1. Localization - Try to set the local to US and check if that helps.
2. Problem with some old .net framework installation - Try to uninstalling all of older .net frameworks in your machine and then install .net 4.0 full and launch CSRUN with Emulator again.
3. VC++ runtime incompatibility: Try removing VC++ runtime in your machine and then install 64bit VC++ runtime

Try making sure above changes and then check if that resolves the problem.